# Is there any Alternative of --guess in java runcukes

Tags: java, cucumber, appium, calabash, cucumber-java

i am getting an error `cucumber.runtime.AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException: ✽.Then I should validate my username with expected value (features/sanity.feature:32) matches more than one step definition:
  ^I should validate ([^"]*) with expected value in UserSteps.iShouldValidateWithExpectedValue(String)
  ^I should validate my username with expected value$ in HomeSteps.iShouldValidateMyUsernameWithExpectedValue()

`

When i run with calabash i use to add "--guess" in the run command.

But Don't know how to resolve the same in CucumberJvm in Java.

Is there any possiblities to add this in @cucumberoptions ?

Am using the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**--guess** is not an option that you can set in the [command line runner](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/45ee6743517968ee086f674f941334660bdc4f82/core/src/main/resources/cucumber/api/cli/USAGE.txt).  Recall that cucumber can always guess wrong.  I recommend that you simply change a few words near the beginning of the failing statement to make sure that that statement is unique.  Better safe than sorry.

Searching through the cucumber-jvm source, there is at least [one reference](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/45ee6743517968ee086f674f941334660bdc4f82/examples/groovy-calculator/src/test/groovy/calc/CalculatorSteps.groovy) to **--guess** being set by default.

Comment: Many thanks Mike, I have an other idea how about introducing " " double quotes in the feature file to get the strings. But my concern is will it be readable and is it a proper way of writing feature file

Comment: Not sure that I completely understand you.  I routinely use double quotes around parameters in my feature files.  In step definitions, I use ... \"(.*)\" ... to escape the double quotes and to capture the parameter.